# Efficient zip of two DataStreams in Flink (join with position as implicit key)

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm interested in efficiently zipping together two data streams using Apache Flink (but the same problem may also apply to data sets).

As an example (using Scala notation) I have

```
names: DataStream[String]
ages: DataStream[Int]
```

and I want to obtain

```
combined: DataStream[(String, Int)]
```

where the join is made implicitly using the position of the data inside the stream (informally: `combined(i) = (names(i), ages(i))`). I can obtain this by adding a "position" field to each stream and then joining them together using the position as a key, but this is quite inefficient.

Are there any better ways of doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom `CoFlatMap` function. For this to work, you will need two internal FIFO buffers, too, because both map methods will be called in unpredictable order (depending when data is available for the two inputs).

Thus, you algorithm will work as follows (same algorithm for both map functions):

1. on each call, append input tuple to own buffer
2. while other buffer and own buffer is not empty, take a tuple from each buffer and emit the combined tuple

Of course, you can apply some more optimization to this algorithm -- this version only illustrates the main idea.

Comment: Assuming that the streams are big (not fitting in RAM) and they are loaded unpredictably (for example, first stream 1 and then stream 2), wouldn't this lead to an overflow, caused by one of the FIFO growing unbound?

Comment: Yes. This solution only works if both streams are delivered with a bounded offset (ie, that there is enough memory to buffer the records). Of course, you could extend this, to buffer on disc instead of in-memory. Thus using a fixed number of tuples you buffer in-memory, and spill to disc if your threshold gets exceeded.